# XCode 5 Freezes When Loading One Project

Tags: ios, xcode5

When I load one specific project, XCode 5 freezes all the time on my iMac. I tried to get a clean project from our code repository and same thing. The same project doesn't freeze on my laptop and also other users don't see the freeze. It usually takes about 1 minute or less to freeze. Other projects are fine. I tried to delete the workspace file but no go.

Version 5.0.2 (5A3005)

Comment: have you tried making a new project and importing the source files?

Comment: Try opening one file at a time and see if it is a particular file.